# Hide form in angular 5

Tags: angular, html, typescript

I'm trying to make the terms of use appear on the first screen with two buttons, in case the user hit the accept button, it is directed to the authentication form but if you click on refuse will appear the "Refused Terms" screen.
I've already done some tests but I'm having difficulties. Follow the code I've already done.

#### app.component.html

```html
<div align="center" class="rounded float-center box-login"><br>
  <p> odas as tarefas ou módulos de entrega só devem ser considerados concluídos com o termo de aceite em mãos. Antes disso, é mera especulação. Entregas aceitas são uma saída do processo Validar o escopo, da área de conhecimento de gerenciamento do escopo.
    . Apresentação do Documento Um projeto só pode ser encerrado formalmente a partir do aceite

    <button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Aceitar</button>
    <button mat-button type="submit" class="btn-recused btn-danger">Recusar</button> </p>

  <div *ngIf="visible; then everClicked else oddClicked"></div>
  <button (click)="toggleDiv()">Aceitar os termos</button>


  <ng-template #everClicked>

  </ng-template>

</div>

<ng-template #oddClicked>
  <div class="">
    <div class="row">

      <div align="center" class="rounded float-center box-login">
        <br>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="assets/images/logo.png" style="width:46%">
        </div>

        <br>

        <form [formGroup]="userForm" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">

          <mat-form-field class="hcs-full-width">

            <input matInput placeholder="Nome" [formControl]="nameFormControl" [(ngModel)]="name">
            <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
              Nome é
              <strong>requirido</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>


          <mat-form-field class="hcs-full-width">

            <input matInput placeholder="CPF" [formControl]="nameFormControl" [(ngModel)]="cpf" [cpf]="cpf">
            <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
              CPF é
              <strong>requirido</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <!--
            <mat-form-field class="hcs-full-width">
              <input matInput name="cpf" placeholder="CPF" formControlName="cpf" [cpf]="cpf" [(ngModel)]="cpf" required>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formErrorMsgOf(loginForm,'cpf','required')">
                CPF é requirido
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="formErrorMsgOf(loginForm,'cpf','cpf')">
                <strong> Por favor entre com um CPF valido</strong>
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>-->



          <mat-form-field class="hcs-full-width">
            <input matInput placeholder="E-mail" [formControl]="emailFormControl" [(ngModel)]="email">
            <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email') && !emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
              Por favor entre com um endereço de e-mail valido
            </mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
              E-mail é
              <strong>requirido</strong>
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>

          <br>


          <br>

          <button mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block button-size" (click)="Logar()">Enviar</button>

          <div class="space"></div>

        </form>


        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>


</ng-template>
```

#### app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
visible = true;
toggleDiv(){
  this.visible=false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the difficult you faced ?

Comment: can you generate a simple app in StackBlitz or JSFiddle to describe your problem?

Comment: the difficulty I face is to hide the button and the terms of use and only show the login screen

Answer (score 0):

Just change your toggle `visible` on button `click`

```
<button (click)="visible=true" mat-button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Aceitar</button>
<button (click)="visible=false" mat-button type="submit" class="btn-recused btn-danger">Recusar</button> </p>
```

> Note : You can reverse your condition as per requirement.

Comment: Hello, I managed to make clicking on accept it 'redirected to login. now I would like to know how to refuse to redirect it to another screen

Comment: You meant you don't user to redirect to any page other than login page ?

Comment: yes, when I click the refuse button it appears the message but on the same page of the terms, and I wanted it to be redirected to another page